# Count total posts related to a forum - PHP Logic

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with figuring out the logic for this, because in the most tutorials i saw, they just had to store a topics_count int in the database and every time a topic was created in that specific forum they would increase the topics_count +1 for the forum they were created in;

however can't we achieve this by getting a value using `mysqli_num_rows` instead? This would return the total rows (topics) in relation with a forum. But then the problem is how can i create that relation when the forums are inside an array.

Both forums and topics have an:

- id
- title
- description

I am aware of the security problems. This example is just a practice.

This is how i display the forums from the database and echo a href to each forum.

```
                $array_forums = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_forums); 
                    echo "<div id='forum_{$array_forums["forum_id"]}' class='forum_classic'>";
                        echo "<div id='forum_classic_status'></div>";                           
                        echo "<div id='forum_classic_container'>";
                            echo "<div id='forum_classic_icon'></div>";
                            echo "<div id='forum_classic_description'>";
                                    echo "<a href=forum.php?forum=" . urlencode($array_forums["forum_id"]) . ">";
                                        echo "<h1>{$array_forums["forum_title"]}</h1>";
                                    echo "</a>";
                                echo "<p>{$array_forums["forum_description"]}</p>";
                            echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div id='forum_classic_topics'>Topics</div>";
                        echo "<div id='forum_classic_replies'>Replies</div>";
                        echo "<div id='forum_classic_lastposter'>Lastposter</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
```

This is how i display the topics in each forum, after a link is clicked.

```
            $forum_id = $_GET['forum'];

            //1. Perform database query for topics
            $sql_topic = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topic_forum_id = {$forum_id}";
            $res_topic = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_topic);
            //2. Display returned data from topics
            if (mysqli_num_rows($res_topic) >= 1) {
                $array_topic = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_topic);
                echo "<div id='topic_{$array_topic["topic_id"]}'>{$array_topic["topic_title"]}";
                echo "</div>";
            } else {
                echo "<a href='community.php'>Return To Forum Index</a>";
                echo "<p>There are no topics in this forum yet.</p>";
            }
```

Comment: I am not being able to understand you requirement can you explain it

Comment: Basically this is the code i use to display the forums and the topics related to them, now i wonder how to implement a topic counter, to count how many topics there are inside a forum.

Comment: $sql_topic = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topic_forum_id = {$forum_id} COUNT(id) as count"; change id to something else if you dont  use id in your database. When you var_dump your $sql_topic, you'll notice 'count' as key and a value next to it. Can you try and let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use count to count the number of rows

```
$sql_topic = "SELECT count(*) FROM topics WHERE topic_forum_id = {$forum_id}";
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql_topic);
$num = $row[0];
```

$num will return the number of topics in specific forum

Comment: great job, with your help i managed to do it. However i made a small tweak, because this needed to work in the same page as the forums, and i was getting the {$forum_id} once i click inside the forum, from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @Anil Shrestha , $num will serve as the topic counter.

```
                    $sql_topic = "SELECT count(*) FROM topics WHERE topic_forum_id = {$array_forums["forum_id"]}";
                    $res_topic = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_topic);
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($res_topic);
                    $num = $row[0];
```

Comment: Great keep it on bro